# How does the pascal for loop work?

Tags: pascal

I've got a question related to the way the for loop works in Pascal:

```
Program example;
var i:integer;
Begin
     i:=7;
     for i:=1 to i do write(i);
End.
```

This piece of code outputs: `1234567`.
I think that the compiler makes a secondary copy of the variable `i`, and then uses that one in the `for` loop.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a title that actually describes your problem.

Comment: Sorry about that but I didn't really know what title to choose since I just want to know why that piece of code executes properly(why does the pascal for loop work like that?).

Comment: My pascal is rusty but essentially the value of **i** is set as the termination of the loop at the commencement of the loop; even before i:=1. For the same reason you can write i:=i*2. First i × 2 is processed then the result is returned to i.

Comment: You could run `fpc -a ...` on your file and it will provide you the assembly language translation (assuming you're using Free Pascal). When I ran it, it did indeed first store the value of `i` (having just assigned 7) to the `%si` register, then executed the loop comparing the index to `%si`. So your speculation as to how it works seems correct, but I would certainly avoid writing code like that unless it was (for some reason) absolutely necessary. I couldn't say for certain that all Pascal compilers would interpret the code in that way.

Comment: Afaik the rule is that the upper and lower bounds are only evaluated once.  If there is no register free, it is stored in a temp on the stack

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!It's not the fact that I want to write code like this but it just seemed strange to me that this code would work so I had to ask.

Comment: The loop will in fact do this (using a hidden variable or register which I call `endloop`here): `endloop := i; i := 1; while i < endloop do begin write(i); inc(i); end;`. That's it. No second variable `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `for loop` in Pascal we have variable called `loop counter` which controls the iterations of the loop, and this **variable changes in each iteration of the loop**, so it's that `i` which is declared here: `i:=1` in your code.

The second is the variable declared above the loop which is called also `i` but it's a variable which is the `final value` for the loop.

Consider this:

```
Program example;
var i:integer;
var addr:^word;
Begin
     i:=10; 
     for i:=1 to i do addr:=@i;
     addr^ := addr^+1; { I add 1 to the last loop counter }
     writeln(i);       { This is final variable, I don't add anything to the final variable of the loop }
     writeln(addr^);   { This is value of the last loop counter index  }
                { Both variables give us the same result }
                { Proposal: In my opinion, your guess about the copy is correct } 
End.
```

As in comment in the code - in my opinion, pascal **creates a copy of this variable**.

Hope it will help! 
If yes please let me know by voting up.

Regards!

Comment: First,thanks for your help!Pascal does create a copy of the variable,if you take a look into the asm generated by fpc(as suggested by @lurker ) you can see the following: `movw U_P$EX_I,%si`,where `U_P$EX_I` is the value of `i`.

Comment: I haven't got an access to the pascal compiler besides the Ideone where I produced, in the sweat of one's brow, this code which shows the answer for your question from the Pascal point of view!  :)
Best regards!

Answer (score 3):

Note that this is REQUIRED to work in Pascal according to the ISO7185 standard. The "end value" should be copied before the loop counter is modified.

https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/test/Basic/iso7185pat.pas#L761

Answer (score 2):

The point here is the Pascal compiler will set the parameters for the **for** once, at the first execution. Then it sets a start point **i:=1** and and end point **7** before doing anything with the control value, then starts the loop.

But I should point that this is **bad practice** in programming. Unless you are just making an academical or speculative question, I see no reason to "save" a  variable name doing something like this.

It is interesting to notice too that this abuse of the control variable name may cause unpredictable results if this is done inside the loop.

As they use to say in those programs who show dangerous adventures, don't try to do this at home!

Comment: The example above is for academical purpose indeed.As for modifying the `counter variable` inside the `for-loop`,it can't be done,as `free pascal` will output an error.Consider the following example:`Program example2; var i:integer; Begin for i:=1 to 7 do i:=5; End.`.It won't work due to an `illegal assignment to for-loop variable`,well,at least that's what you get when trying to compile it with `free pascal`,I'm not sure about the other compilers.

Comment: Same in Delphi, Turbo Pascal, etc. although the exact text of the error message may differ.